# Proper syntax for installing mysql2 gem pre-version 0.3.0 with MYSQL LIB and INCLUDE options on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-7, rake, mysql2

There must a million variations of this problem but I don't seem to be finding any answers.

I spent the afternoon looking for a way to install MYSQL 5.5 on my Windows 7, 64-bit machine and install the mysql2 gem.  Finally I found Lukom's comment at the [RORGUIDE](http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html) blog and I was off and running with this code:

```
gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\TEMP\msi\Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\TEMP\msi\Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"'
```

So, this installs the 0.3.6 version of the mysql2 gem.  Hooray!  However, when I try to run the db:create I get the following error:

```
WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.3.6) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1
WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x
```

So I figure all I have to do is uninstall the gem and reinstall a version less that 0.3.0 and I am back on track.  However, I cannot find the code to properly indicate the gem version AND my lib/include arguments.  Here is my best attempt and the error:

```
gem install mysql2 --version "0.2.7" '--with-mysql-lib="C:\TEMP\msi\Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\TEMP\msi\Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"'

invalid option: --with-mysql-lib=C:\TEMP\msi\Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib
```

So I am at a loss.  I don't want to upgrade to the Rails pre-release because I don't enjoy troubleshooting that much.  I am sure this is a simple syntax error and I would appreciate anyone who can show me the correct command for both the version and lib/include arguments.

Thanks in advance,

Byron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
gem install mysql2 --version '0.2.7' -- --with-mysql-lib="C:\TEMP\msi\Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\TEMP\msi\Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"
```

Comment: You are so close I have to give it to you. This is the code that worked: `gem install mysql2 --version '0.2.7' --' --with-mysql-lib="C:\TEMP\msi\Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\TEMP\msi\Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"` The only difference in the apostrophe after the version statement and before the lib arguement. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Byron!  I tried a few variations, but couldn't fully verify that it worked since I'm on Mac OSX :)  Glad you figured it out and thanks for posting what worked.  I will update my answer

Comment: Well you are going to thing I'm loosing it.  I installed the same gem on a different instance of rails, same OS, same MySQL version, same everything.  The syntax with the apostrophe did not work but your original suggestion did.  I guess I am going to have to just keep a record of all the command variations worth trying so that in the future I can try them all until something works.  Thanks again for your response.